# Allow only registered users to comment on WordPress blog posts

Tags: wordpress

The question is quite simple : How can I restrict unregistered users to post on my WordPress blog?
I was thinking about a plugin that would hide the "comments" part if user is not logged in, but 1) I don't know if it is possible, and 2) there is certainly a easier way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like a comment to explain when someone downvote...

Comment: I suspect it may have been because it's not really a programming question, it's just down to how to use WordPress, and could be argued that it might not belong on StackOverflow.  I've learned not to take downvotes on SO personally - best to just shrug and move on :)

Comment: Good point. I was not taking this personally... just want to know what is wrong. Moving on ;)

Comment: I flagged this question for moderator review; it should be migrated to the [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under 'Discussion Settings' you'll find the option: 'Users must be registered and logged in to comment'.

(From your Wordpress admin dashboard, click 'Settings', then 'Discussion', and you'll find it there.)

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for "comments" instead of "discussion".

Comment: You can tick the Users must be registered and logged in to comment option in Setting > Discussion > Other comment settings @johnny5